# Class<Result> cannot be converted to Class<Result<Integer>>

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have and API method declared as following

```
public class Dummy {
    public static class Result<ValueT extends Comparable> {
        public ValueT value;
    }

    public static <ValueT extends Comparable> Result<ValueT> 
            getResult(Class<? extends Result<ValueT>> ofType) throws Exception {
        return ofType.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to invoke it relying on Java compile-time type verification and just can't find correct syntax to do this:

Attempts:

**`getResult(Result<Integer>.class)`** `<-- expected syntax`

```
public static void invokeGetResult() {
    Result<Integer> intResult = getResult(Result<Integer>.class);
}
```

results in

```
error: <identifier> expected
  Result<Integer> intResult = getResult(Result<Integer>.class);
                                                        ^
```

**`getResult(Result.class)`** `<-- just to try`

```
public static void invokeGetResult() {
    Result<Integer> intResult = getResult(Result.class);
}
```

results in

```
error: method getResult in class Dummy cannot be applied to given types;
    Result<Integer> intResult = getResult(Result.class);
                                ^
  required: Class<? extends Result<ValueT>>
  found: Class<Result>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) ValueT
    (argument mismatch; Class<Result> cannot be converted to Class<? extends Result<ValueT>>)
  where ValueT is a type-variable:
    ValueT extends Comparable declared in method <ValueT>getResult(Class<? extends Result<ValueT>>)
```

**`getResult((Class<Result<Integer>>)Result.class)`** `<-- just to try`

```
public static void invokeGetResult() {
    Result<Integer> intResult = getResult((Class<Result<Integer>>)Result.class);
}
```

results in

```
error: incompatible types: Class<Result> cannot be converted to Class<Result<Integer>>
    Result<Integer> intResult = getResult((Class<Result<Integer>>)Result.class);
                                                                        ^
```

Comment: you should be using `<ValueT extends Comparable<? super ValueT>>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: I did not understand clearly the original intentions. This example should work for your call, however it is a bit hacky and not so recommended.

```
public class Dummy {
    public static class Result<ValueT extends Comparable> {
        public ValueT value;
    }

    public static <ValueT extends Comparable> Result<ValueT>
        getResult(Class<? extends Result<ValueT>> ofType) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Dummy.Result<Integer> result = Dummy.getResult(new Result<Integer>(){}.getClass());
```

The compile time verification should work with this example, as you are creating an anonymous empty class and it's type information can be retrieved successfully.

You could also do a type cast as @Jorn suggested in comments, although your compiler will warn you about the fact it is an "unchecked cast".

Comment: No, this over-simplification of the original use-case - various sub-classes of `Dummy.Result` should be conditionally created depending in argument, that's why method is declared as `getResult(Class<? extends Result<ValueT>> ofType)`

Comment: Then the only way is to implement a class extending `Result<Integer>` and pass it as the `getResult` parameter. As far as I know, type erasure kicks in all the examples given in the questions, and I am not sure there is a simpler way of doing it without creating new classes.

Comment: Final 'class' is known only by client code. The problem occurs in the intermediate API method, where code is only aware about some base `Result` class  to operate on and its value type.

Comment: Ok, let me change my answer to solve something closer to the original question. But I still think there is no way to call the method in a "nice generic" way without doing some unchecked casts, implementing a new class or some hacky tricks.

Comment: I feel I oversimplified my question from the real life. As i mentioned in comments to @Jorns answer - class instance provided as parameter can be 'abstract', some sub-class will be instantiated by API - that is why "new Result()" will just not work in more generic case than I explicitly asked. ... OK, I feel there is no really good solution for the question and I already ended up with casting back from raw Class with suppression of warnings - '@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Result<Integer> intResult = getResult((Class)Result.class);' I'll accept your answer since it has mention of this.

Comment: The `ofType` parameter is completely unused, and should be removed. There's no point to passing anything in.

Comment: @newacct I am obviously returning `null` as a placeholder, as I assume @XtraCoder is performing some logic inside `getResult`, as it was stated several times that his question has been oversimplified from real-life. I can obviously see `ofType` is unused (if that was the reason for the downvote). On the other hand, if you read my comments, you will see I mention type erasure and reification as the real source of the issue here, as you do in your answer. Nonetheless, @XtraCoder wanted a way of invoking the method relying on compile time type-verification so that was the focus of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of passing the `Class<...>` is to instantiate it, consider using a `Supplier<...>` instead. It does not have this problem, and does not throw any exceptions.

Here is an example:

```
class SomeClass extends Result<Integer> {...}

public static <T extends Result<?>> T getResult(Supplier<T> constructor) {
   return constructor.get();
}
```

Use like:

```
getResult(SomeClass::new); // Passes the constructor.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in my use-case - resulting object will be actually created via de-serialization and de-serialization API in use accepts Class as type information. It may have sense to redesign serialization API to accept Supplier - but this will bring other problems: (1) type information will be available only after instance is created (via instance.getClass()) and (2) it will not be possible to pass an abstract class - in some cases serialization API my create particular sub-class depending on runtime configuration.

Comment: I am not sure you can do what you are trying to do in Java. Type information is not stored in Generic classes due to type erasure and not reification.

Comment: @XtraCoder What de-serialization API are you using? They usually have their own ways of dealing with generic classes.

Comment: @Jose - I do not care about type erasure because correct value of ValueT will be created from data type in source data (and at the moment it is actually limited to String or Integer). I only care that one set of classes will have Integer as value and another one - String, and correct usage in code should be checked at build time.

Comment: @Jorn - it is some sort of proprietary API on top of Jackson JSON lib. But ... it does not matter actually. That question is more a generic-purposes theoretical one than attempt to fix particular implementation issue.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really such thing as a `Class<Result<Integer>>`. `Class` objects represent reifiable classes at runtime, and there is only one single `Class` object at runtime for the class `Result`, which you can get via the expression `Result.class`, which has type `Class<Result>`. There are no `Class` objects representing `Result<Integer>` or `Result<String>`, etc.

You can take the expression of type `Class<Result>` (which you get from `Result.class`) and do a bunch of unsafe casts on it to turn it into a `Class<Result<Integer>>` or something like that, for example:

```
`(Class<Result<Integer>>)(Class<?>)Result.class`
```

but not that this is *unsafe*. It is unsafe because the interface of `Class` has certain methods that return `T` (the type parameter of the class `Class`) based on runtime type operations with the class. For example, `Class` has a method `.cast()` which checks whether the passed object is an instance of the class, and if not, throws an exception, and if it is, then returns the object, as type `T`. If you call `Result.class.cast()`, it returns a `Result`, and the method indeed checks at runtime that the object is a `Result`. But if you call `.cast()` on an expression of type `Class<Result<Integer>>`, it returns type `Result<Integer>`, but the class could not have checked at runtime that the thing is a `Result<Integer>`, because 1) this is just the same `Result` class object, and 2) generic information doesn't exist at runtime. So you would get a `Result<Integer>` that might not be a `Result<Integer>`.

So basically, you need to think about what you are using this class object to do, and how it makes sense to have it as a `Class<Result<Integer>>` when all you can have at runtime is a class object representing the raw type `Result`.

Here you have a method that takes `Class<? extends Result<ValueT>>`. I am wondering why you have the wildcard here. Are you trying to have it accept subclasses of `Result`? Because if not, then the only thing that can be passed in is the unique `Result` class object itself, which means the parameter is basically pointless because it's always the same thing that can be passed in; in that case you might as well get rid of the parameter and just do:

```
public static <ValueT extends Comparable<? super ValueT>> Result<ValueT> 
        getResult() throws Exception {
    return new Result<ValueT>();
}
```

If you are going to accept subclasses of `Result`, then you're assuming that all subclasses must have a no-parameter constructor, as you are calling `.newInstance()` on it, which is bad design. You should use something like a `Supplier` as Jorn Vernee's answer suggests.